# How do I get my hp pro P1102w to connect to network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer

I am trying to set up my wireless HP LaserJet Pro P1102w to my laptop. I followed the instructions on how to do it wirelessly. When I get the Configuration page I get an error note saying "HP Web Services requires the printer to be connected to a network. I am currently using a different wireless router than the previous one. This one has a different name and password and the printer and laptop is not recognizing it.

Comment: sounds trivial, but have you tried to contact HP for support? http://support.hp.com/

Comment: If neither your laptop nor printer can get on the network, then your network isn't setup correctly.

Comment: I am currently on my laptops network and the router recognizes the laptop. It's just the printer. It's still seeing my old router. Also, I haven't contacted HP but I have read almost everything on the subject. It's probably something easy to fix and I'm just making it seem harder than it is to take care of. I tend to overthink. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a defect in the design of the configuration protocol.  When the printer obtains a dynamic IP address, it does not seem to bother to update the Windows box's configuration (or the Windows software does not bother to listen for the updates).  I could work this around.

- I temporarily turned off the WiFi connection of the device that took over the original IP address of the printer.  By the "original address" I mean one that was stored in the printer registration in the Windows box.  The HP All-in-One application shows this original address.  The application shows up after double-clicking the printer icon in Windows 10.
- I narrowed the DHCP lease range in the router to exclude the printer's original address from being taken by any other wireless device.
- I then configured the printer hardware to use its original IP address by switching to the "manual" IP configuration in its web interface available by the current IP address and setting the address to the original one.  The web interface will stop responding after saving the change but will show up after opening the original IP address in the browser.

I also heard of the printer's *wificonfig* application that can be found in the *program files\hp* folder.  It may require a USB cable connection.